# Error in installing revel: undefined: config.DEFAULT_SECTION

Tags: go, revel, bunch

I am installing revel using Bunch .
I am getting below error:

```
installing github.com/revel/revel ... 2017/03/27 13:49:41 failed installing packages: failed building package github.com/revel/revel, error: # github.com/revel/revel
./revel.go:180: undefined: config.DEFAULT_SECTION
, output: %!s(MISSING): exit status 2 [exit status 2 github.com/dkulchenko/bunch/packages.go:234: failed building package github.com/revel/revel, error: # github.com/revel/revel
./revel.go:180: undefined: config.DEFAULT_SECTION
, output: %!s(MISSING) github.com/dkulchenko/bunch/packages.go:643: ]
```

Please help me with this and let me know how to resolve this problem.

Below is how my BunchFile look:

```
github.com/dkulchenko/bunch !self

github.com/robfig/config
github.com/revel/revel v0.13.0
github.com/revel/cmd/revel v0.13.0
github.com/janekolszak/revmgo
github.com/afex/hystrix-go/hystrix
github.com/remind101/newrelic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revel changed the CONFIG_DEFAULT variable name in `github.com/revel/config/config.go` a [while ago](https://github.com/revel/config/commit/0f92ab2596a3f41d6b6dbb8c5f02054d626afd95#diff-b4bda758a2aef091432646c354b4dc59)

You probably need to pin that repository at v0.13.0 also, presumably by adding this to your bunch file:

`github.com/revel/config v0.13.0`

You could also remove your pin of revel to v0.13.0 and get a more recent version.